# IIS 7.5 multiple static sites and one application pool

Tags: iis-7.5, application-pool

I have have a server hosting about 40 static sites, all HTML, no server-side code. I would like to make this server a bit more efficient by collapsing all the application pools into one. Right now, each site has its own app pool, which would make sense if there was any code to execute.

So my question is: Is it safe to host 40 sites from one app-pool even if they're all static sites? And will there be an performance benefits from this? (i.e. less memory used?)

thanks!